# Magento admin save product fails if description has html tags

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, products-management, cms-block

If I add any html-tags to my product description, short description or CMS Static block and click save it fails and no data is saved. It makes no difference if I enter the html-tags myself or do everything through the WYSIWYG editor. (I have enabled WYSIWYG for description/short description)
Example:
Edit description:

```
<p>Hello</p> 
<p>World</p>
```

Click Save-> (For product I am redirected to dashboard. For CMS block I get a 403.)
Nothing saved.

If I avoid any html tags then the item is saved and all works well.

This issue is still happening and there is an additional report here which also sadly has been closed:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80195/no-permissions-to-create-a-cms-block-in-backend

Comment: Still no solution other than avoiding html. :-(
Similar problem exist for saving cms static blocks where if they have any HTML then the save failes, however there I get a 403 instead.
Thanks for any input!

Comment: Desperate for help. I am dependent on cms static blocks and right now I can't do any updates to them whatsoever.
What does Magento do differently if HTML is present in a cms block or a product description?

Comment: Anybody give any more hints?

Comment: I am still having this issue. No HTML allowed in product description or cms static blocks. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Wohooo!!! I figured it out what the problem was! With Mod_Sec disabled all works as it should! Now I just need to figure out how I can keep things secure.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when

1. You try have ***Add Secret Key to URLs*** set to ***Yes*** in `System > Configuration > Admin > Security` and you have some module overriding the core one but doesn't take into consideration the mentioned setting.

   Or

   Your URL to pointing to the ***saveAction*** doesn't use the `getUrl()`.
2. The ***saveAction*** throws some sort of errors.

Please check these things first.

Comment: Setting 'Add Secret Key to URLs' to No did not help.

Comment: Have no non-standard files with references to "saveAction". Also, happens in a clean install without any plug-ins. Could anything in the db affect this?

Comment: I looked more into the saveAction and the error happens prior to the saveAction for the block been called. If I don't write any html code in the block then I see the call to block saveAction but if I do write html code in the block then I get 403 prior to saveAction been called.

Answer (score 1):

*Default magento should not behave in this way.*

So try this.

1. Disable extensions one by one under `app > etc > modules` by renaming them.
2. Test if admin save with html tags works after this.
3. If that fixes the problem, then re-enable one by one each extension.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Tried disabling all I have installed again today and didn't help.

Comment: So this is a clean install?

Comment: Did a clean install but using same db. Still getting fault. In a similar fashion, when adding HTML to a cms static block I get a 403. Without HTML it works fine.